How can you work on a mesh in rest position?
Is there a way to orient a mesh to the global XYZ temporarily, or the viewport camera to the active mesh local XYZ? It's easier to do editing on a mesh when the transforms are removed, but it's a hassle if there's already an easy way to do it. I call it rest position because it's similar to an armature rest position.

Does temporarily switching the Transform Orientation on the top toolbar from Global to Local do what you need?

I picture it toggling so that it will align with global while you edit, then you toggle back to the current active transform.

I can see what you mean but I don't think there's an easy way to do that. See if @Lauloques answer helps.

It's more of a way around, but you could snap your 3D cursor to your object's origin and then set your transform orientation to the 3D cursor.

Change your transform orientation to Local


Select the object you want to snap to

Select the cursor tool in the toolbar


Change its orientation setting from None to Transform


Click anywhere in the viewport to move the cursor, which will align its orientation with the selected object's.

Press ⇧ Shift S > Cursor To Selected to snap the cursor location to the object origin.

Change your transform orientation to Cursor



Then your gizmo and your operators' default orientation are aligned with your objects:

